# The CompileAppManifest task was not given a value for required parameter BundleIdentifier"

Tags: xamarin.ios

Every time I am building a project there is "The CompileAppManifest task was not given a value for required parameter BundleIdentifier" (MSB4044)" error. I have not made any change in manifest file and created a simple single view application.This is happening with each and every project which I made.I had even reinstalled Xcode and Visual Studio still the problem persists.